# Trying to make ImageView Array stay in screen bound

Tags: android

I want to create 10 `ImageViews` in random position and I want them to be the same, I tried using `ImageView[]`, I got the screen size(width and height) and created random place for each `ImageView` (in range of screen size). Some of the `ImageViews` are out of bounds as there are sometimes 7,8 `ImageViews` I can see. here's my code:

```
 ImageView ball[], you;
    int layoutwidth, layoutheight;
    Random rand = new Random();
    RelativeLayout rlt;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        rlt = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rlt);
        you = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);
        layoutwidth = size.x;
        layoutheight = size.y;
        ball = new ImageView[11];
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            ball[i] = new ImageView(this);
            ball[i].setTag(i);
            ball[i].setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.ball);
            int randomx = rand.nextInt(layoutwidth+1);
            int randomy = rand.nextInt(layoutheight+1);
            ball[i].setX(randomx);
            ball[i].setY(randomy);
            rlt.addView(ball[i]);
        }
    }
```

How can I make the code work as I need it?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to replace this

```
int randomx = rand.nextInt(layoutwidth+1);
int randomy = rand.nextInt(layoutheight+1);
ball[i].setX(randomx);
ball[i].setY(randomy);
rlt.addView(ball[i]);
```

with

```
int randomx = rand.nextInt(layoutwidth+1-widthOfImageView);
int randomy = rand.nextInt(layoutheight+1-heightOfImageView);
rlt.addView(ball[i]);   
ball[i].setTranslationX(randomx);
ball[i].setTranslationY(randomy);
```

where **widthOfImageView,heightOfImageView** is imageview's width & height

Comment: Yeah I also tried it inside 'onWindowFocusChanged' , the ImageView height and width returned 115 but also, same result.

Comment: Still inside the onWindowFocusChanged?

Comment: try first in on create itself, without imageview width, height

Comment: Both didn't work, also - when it is onWindowFocusChanged if I pause the application or something it creates another 10 ImageViews..